# BigQuery - remove duplicate substrings from string

Tags: google-bigquery, re2

I have a string which contains repeated substrings like

```
The big black dog big black dog is a friendly friendly dog who who lives nearby nearby
```

How can I remove these in BQ so that the result looks like this

```
The big black dog is a friendly dog who lives nearby
```

I tried with regex capturing groups like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38683695/165130) but no luck so far, it just returns the original phrase

```
with text as (
  select "The big black dog big black dog is a friendly 
        friendly dog who who lives nearby nearby" as phrase
)

select REGEXP_REPLACE(phrase,r'([ \\w]+)\\1',r'$1') from text
```

Edit: assuming the repeated word or phrase **follows right after** the first instance of a word or phrase

i.e. `dog dog` is considered a repetition of `dog`,
but `dog good dog` is not

similarly for phrases:

`good dog good dog` is repetition of `good dog`

but `good dog catch ball good dog` is not considered a repetition

Comment: **dog** is aslo a repeated substring as well, isn't it ?

Comment: assuming the repeated word or phrase follows right after the first instance of a  word or phrase

Comment: so "dog" is repeated only if it follows "dog", to answer your question, i.e. "dog dog" should become "dog"

Comment: but if it occurs somewhere else in the phrase as in original example it's not considered repeated

Comment: added example to the question

Comment: Hi @alex, for your requirement, can you try this regex `\\b(\\w+)(?:\\W+\\1\\b)+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Mikhail's wonderful SQL-ish approach, you might consider below **regexp** JS UDF approach.

[regular expression explanation](https://regex101.com/r/S7gM9C/1)

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION dedup_repetition(s STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS
"""
  const re = /(.{2,}) (?=\\1)/g;
  return s.replace(re, '');
""";

WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 'The big black dog big black dog is a friendly friendly dog who who lives nearby nearby' phrase UNION ALL
  SELECT 'good dog good dog' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'good dog good dog good dog' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'good dog good dog good' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dog dog dog' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'good dog catch ball good dog'
)
SELECT dedup_repetition(phrase) deduped_phrase FROM sample_data;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider below naive approach

```
with recursive candidates as (
  select id, phrase, offset_a, len, string_agg(word_b, ' ' order by offset_b) seq
  from your_table, unnest([0,1,2,3,4,5]) as len,
  unnest(split(phrase, ' ')) word_a with offset offset_a  
  join unnest(split(phrase, ' ')) word_b with offset offset_b
  on offset_b between offset_a and offset_a + len  
  group by id, phrase, offset_a, len
), dups as (
  select id,phrase, seq, row_number() over(partition by phrase order by array_length(split(seq, ' ')) desc) as pos
  from (
    select distinct t1.id, t1.phrase, t1.offset_a, t1.seq
    from candidates t1 
    join candidates t2
    on t1.seq = t2.seq
    and t1.phrase = t2.phrase
    and t1.offset_a = t2.offset_a + t2.len + 1
  )
), iterations as (
  select id, phrase, 1 as pos, phrase || ' ' as dedupped_phrase from your_table
  union all 
  select i.id, i.phrase, pos + 1, regexp_replace(dedupped_phrase, r'(' || seq || ' )+', '' || seq || ' ')
  from iterations i
  join dups d
  using(pos, phrase, id)
) 
select id, phrase, trim(dedupped_phrase) as dedupped_phrase
from iterations
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by phrase order by pos desc)
```

So, assuming your_table is

[image]

the output is

[image]

- Step 1 - CTE named `candidates` - here you are getting all possible words sequences to then consider in next step. Note: here in `unnest([0,1,2,3,4,5]) len` you are setting possible length of sequebces (number of words) to consider. you can use `unnest(generate_array(0,5)) as len` instead if you want to save some typing :o)
- Step 2 - CTE named `dups` identifies duplicate sequences obtained in previous step and ranks them from most lengthy (by words count) to least ones
- Step 3- CTE named `iterations` actually goes and eliminates dups one by one (for every phrase)
- Step 4 - finally, the last SELECT retrieves only last iterations  for each initial phrase