# How to remove adjacent duplicates in a string in BigQuery?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, distinct

I have a table in BigQuery where one of the columns has string values that look like this:

`Page A >> Page A >> Page B >> Page B >> Page A >> Page A >> Page C`

I am trying to find a way to de-duplicate *adjacent* values only, so that the string becomes this:

`Page A >> Page B >> Page A >> Page C`

I have tried converting the string to an array and then using DISTINCT to remove duplicates, then converting back to a string, but I end up with this, which is wrong:

`Page A >> Page B >> Page C`

Can anyone help please? Maybe there's a regex solution? Or was I on the right track with arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below answers for similar question.

- [BigQuery - remove duplicate substrings from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74168705/bigquery-remove-duplicate-substrings-from-string/74175923#74175923)

If applied to your case,

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION dedup_repetition(s STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS
"""
  const re = /(Page .* ?) >> (?=\\1)/g;
  return s.replace(re, '');
""";

WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 'Page A >> Page A >> Page B >> Page B >> Page A >> Page A >> Page C' str
)
SELECT dedup_repetition(str) dedup_str FROM sample_data;
```

**Query results**

[image]

- [regexp101.com explanation](https://regex101.com/r/dTqSHQ/1)